# C# Too many redirections after exporting Excel file

Tags: c#

I'm stuck in the case that I have to export data from a database into Excel.

It's was working but we moved our application into a cloud server and now it's not working for big size excel.
(300k lignes is not working but for 150k is ok).

I got the next error "TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" but it will normally open a pop an for download it.

I try with to put in the web.config the "`<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="860"/>`" but I still have the same error.

This is the function I called to download this:

```
   public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)


        context.HttpContext.Response.ClearContent();
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Charset = "";
        // Add timestamp to filename
        string stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");

        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= ReportMe_Contacts_" + stamp + ".xlsx");
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            workBook.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
            context.HttpContext.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Perhaps the problem with cloud server settings? What service do you use?

Comment: Not sure.  I suspect that a virus checker on server is taking a long time to validate file and causing issue.  I do not think it is a size issue because 300k is small.  Usually size is issue when above 1M (or 10M). I would try increasing the timeout.  I would think executionTimeout="860" is in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm using IIS 7.0. I try with timeout but it's the same issue.